# Make all direct parent list entries selected in mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I'm working on a project where I'm about to use the jQuery plugin mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/).

I already had to do some customisations to fit my needs but I don't know what to do with my current issue. In mmenu, when i click on an list entry I will be navigated to the given href and the clicked item becomes active by mmenus css class ".mm-selected". So far so good.

Now I want to additionally mark the parent list item (and thats parent, and so on until menu root) as selected. This should be so when the user goes one level up in the menu he should be able to see in which category he currently is.

[image: example menu structure where parent of current item gets selected as well]

Below is an example of the menus html structure after mmenu was applied. This shows the code for a menu with 4 main pages (index, page1, page2 and page3) and 3 subpages (2.1, 2.2, 2.3).

```
<nav id="nav" class="mm-menu mm-horizontal mm-offcanvas mm-hasheader mm-current mm-opened">
    <ul class="mm-list mm-panel mm-opened mm-current" id="mm-0">
        <li class="mm-selected">
            <a href="#/index">Index</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/page1">Page 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="mm-subopen mm-fullsubopen" href="#mm-1"></a>
            <span>Page 2</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/Page 3">Page 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="mm-list mm-panel mm-highest" id="mm-1">
        <li class="mm-subtitle">
            <a class="mm-subclose" href="#mm-0">Page 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/page2-1">Page 2.1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/page2-2">Page 2.2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/page2-3">Page 2-3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It would be great if you had some idea where and how I could achive such functionality.

Comment: give us the html structure. or a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

So, for the moment I did some jQuery hacking. This seems to work for my case mentioned above. It should also work for deeper menus as it's using recursion. If there's a better way to achieve this, please let me know.

```
var nav = $("#nav");

nav.find("li > a:not(.mm-subopen)").click(function () {
    nav.find("li.active").removeClass("active");
    selectParentEntry($(this));
});

var selectParentEntry = function (a) {
    var li      = a.parent(),
        ul      = li.parent(),
        back    = ul.find("li > a.mm-subclose").first(),
        cID     = "#" + ul.attr("id"),
        pID     = back.length ? back.attr("href") : null;

    li.addClass("active");

    if (pID != null) {
        var subOpen = nav.find("ul" + pID + " > li > a.mm-subopen").filter(function () {                 
            var self = $(this);
            if (self.attr("href") === cID) return self;
        }).first();

        if (subOpen) selectParentEntry(subOpen);
    }
};
```